# Uploading script gives broken image

Tags: php, thumbnails, image-uploading

This is my image uploading script. It does upload normal images just good as appose to the thumbnails. The normal images are uploaded to the uploads folder and the thumbnails to the uploads/thumbs folder. But the strange thing is: the thumbnails are uploaded, but when going to the image on the server it gives a broken image block like this [x]

Let my guide jou trough my code:

First of all I start with creating variables for each image:

```
//#################### Image upload ########################//
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++) {
$imgtemp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i];
$imgtype = $_FILES["image"]["type"][$i];
$imgsize = $_FILES["image"]["size"][$i];
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"][$i]));
if( $imgtype == 'image/jpeg' ){ $filetype= '.jpg'; }else{ $filetype= str_replace ( 'image/', '', $imgtype ); }
$image_name = md5( rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) ) . '.jpg';
$path= '../../uploads/' . $image_name;
$thumb_name = "thumb_" . md5( rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) ) . '.jpg';
$thumb_path= '../../uploads/thumbs/' . $thumb_name;
$imgsize2= getimagesize( $imgtemp );
$width= $imgsize2[0];
$height= $imgsize2[1];
```

The script underneath checks witch case to take, depending on the variables `$image_thumbheight` and `$image_thumbwidth`

```
//
        if( $width == $height ){ $case=1; }
        if( $width > $height ){ $case=2; }
        if( $width < $height ){ $case=3; }
        if(isEmpty($image_thumbheight) && !isEmpty($image_thumbwidth)){


        switch( $case ){

            case 1:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbwidth;
            $newheight= $image_thumbwidth;

            break;

            case 2:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbwidth;
            $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
            $newheight= $height * $ratio;

            break;

            case 3:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbwidth;
            $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
            $newheight= $height * $ratio;

            break;

            }
        } 
        if(isEmpty($image_thumbheight) && isEmpty($image_thumbwidth)){


        switch( $case ){

            case 1:

            $newwidth= 100;
            $newheight= 100;

            break;

            case 2:

            $newheight= 100;
            $ratio= $newheight / $height;
            $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

            break;

            case 3:

            $newwidth= 100;
            $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
            $newheight= $height * $ratio;

            break;

            }
        } 
        if(!isEmpty($image_thumbheight) && !isEmpty($image_thumbwidth)){


        switch( $case ){

            case 1:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbwidth;
            $newheight= $image_thumbheight;

            break;

            case 2:

            $newheight= $image_thumbheight;
            $ratio= $newheight / $height;
            $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

            break;

            case 3:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbwidth;
            $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
            $newheight= $height * $ratio;

            break;

            }
        } 
        if(!isEmpty($image_thumbheight) && isEmpty($image_thumbwidth)){


        switch( $case ){

            case 1:

            $newwidth= $image_thumbheight;
            $newheight= $image_thumbheight;

            break;

            case 2:

            $newheight= $image_thumbheight;
            $ratio= $newheight / $height;
            $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

            break;

            case 3:

            $newheight= $image_thumbheight;
            $ratio= $newheight / $height;
            $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

            break;

            }
        }
```

I think that the problems lies in the code underneath as this is the final part of the uploading script. It moves the uploaded files to the given paths:

```
            switch( $imgtype ){

                case 'image/jpeg';

                $img= imagecreatefromjpeg( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagejpeg( $thumb, $thumb_path, 70 );  

                break;

                case 'image/png';

                $img= imagecreatefrompng( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagepng( $thumb, $thumb_path, 70 ); 

                break;

                case 'image/gif';

                $img= imagecreatefromgif( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagegif( $thumb, $thumb_path, 70 ); 

                break;


            }
            move_uploaded_file( $imgtemp, $path );
}
```

Can someone figure this out?

Comment: Why are you doing an if to set cases and then also a switch? Why not add everything in the if else statement?

Comment: It does not really matter, but with this method I dont have to retype the if else statement in each of them. But you are right I could have also used your recommended method.